# General constant menu in the application

Tags: android, android-activity, menu

I'm developing an Android application that has 10 different activities with the same constant menu at the  bottom of their screen. Is fragments is the best way to build the menu or just build a base activity class that all the activities inherits from it?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a class let say `MyBaseActivity` that extends `Activity` and in that class take care of displaying that menu etc.

Then you should let all your `Activities` in your application extend your custom `MyBaseActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the bottom line should behave on activity changes. If you want it not to move, you habe to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). For pre-Honeycomb devices you'll need the `Android Compatibility package` provided in the SDK.

If you don't care that the bottom line will be destroyed and recreated on every change of activity, your way to go is as `Ovidiu Latcu` wrote extending a `BaseActivity` which provides just the bottom line.