# Don't repeat menu code

Tags: android, menu

I'd like to have only one menu for all my activities. I don't want to repeat my menu code (below) in all my activities.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.referent, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        System.out.println("set");
        return true;
    case R.id.action_alert:
        System.out.println("alert");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I read some topics, but I found just one solution witch is to extends a parent class who declare the menu. I can't use this solution because all my activities are not extending Activity, I have also have `FragmentActivity` and `ListActivity`.

Is there a solution to have the same menu on each activity writing a minimum of code on each activity?

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727622/general-constant-menu-in-the-application

Comment: thanks but in your link they are using the extends or the fragment, I don't want to use the fragment for compatibility reasons.

Comment: What about composition instead of inheritance? Just pass the `item` and other needed params to the method in another object with common logic.

Comment: If you are concerned about compatibility, you may not want to rule out using fragments just yet.  I've had a lot of success implementing fragments in my applications using the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html).  Implementing is pretty straight forward and IMO you'll be better off coding your app using fragments from the start rather than converting Activity-based code in the future when you want to realize some of the benefits of Fragments (like supporting different screen sizes in unique ways, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what the menu handling code needs access to from the current activity, you could create a class whose only responsability is to handle the selected menu items. Possibly even with just a static method that receives the `MenuItem`.

For example, modify activities such that the `onOptionsItemSelected` is:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    boolean handled = MenuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
    if (!handled) {
        handled = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return handled;
}
```

and create the `MenuHandler` class:

```
public class MenuHandler {
    public static boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1: //R.id.action_settings:
            System.out.println("set");
            return true;
        case 2: //R.id.action_alert:
            System.out.println("alert");
            return true;
        default:
            return false;   //allow default processing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all what you need is to extend from a main class

```
public abstract class main extends activity(){
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// put your common menu code

super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
public class HelloActivity extends main{
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: He explicitly says in the question that he can't use a subclass of the `Activity` class.